# Index not being counted on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a slider where I want to keep track of the current position of the slider. The function that runs when the `('next')` and `('prev')` are being clicked,  is supposed to log the current position of the slider.

Unfortunately it skips the first child and starts the count on the second item in the slider. Instead of the first item being `index 0,` the second item is `index 0`

```
$(document).foundation()
$('.bullet').first().addClass('active');

//sets first item to active
$('.slider-item').first().addClass('active');

function dec() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var current = $('.slider-items').find('.active');
  var position = $('.slider-items').children().index(current);

  console.log(position)
}

$('.next, .prev').click(function() {
  dec();
  var $this = $(this);

  var current = $('.slider-items').find('.active');
  var position = $('.slider-items').children().index(current);

  var numItems = $('.slider-item').length;

  if ($this.hasClass('next')) {
    if (position < numItems - 1) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.slider-item').removeClass('active').first().addClass('active');
      $('.bullet').removeClass('active').first().addClass('active');
    } //else
  } else {
    if (position === 0) {
      $('.slider-item').removeClass('active').last().addClass('active');
      $('.bullet').removeClass('active').last().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
    }
  }
}); // click function
```

Comment: I got an error sadly

Comment: Yikes, you have a **lot** of [brittle code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_brittleness).  I highly suggest reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Comment: try this : position = current.index()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to work when I run it against a simple bullet list example.  It correctly states that the first bullet point is index 0.  Are you simply calling the `dec()` function in the wrong place?  **Note that when you click next, you are logging the current position before the change is made to the position.**  I updated the `dec()` code to accept a parameter to show what I mean.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

//sets first item to active
$('.slider-item').first().addClass('active');

function dec(prefix) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var current = $('.slider-items').find('.active');
  var position = $('.slider-items').children().index(current);

  console.log(prefix + position);
}

$('.next, .prev').click(function() {
  dec("before click handled: ");
  var $this = $(this);

  var current = $('.slider-items').find('.active');
  var position = $('.slider-items').children().index(current);

  var numItems = $('.slider-item').length;

  if ($this.hasClass('next')) {
    if (position < numItems - 1) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.slider-item').removeClass('active').first().addClass('active');
      $('.bullet').removeClass('active').first().addClass('active');
    } //else
  } else {
    if (position === 0) {
      $('.slider-item').removeClass('active').last().addClass('active');
      $('.bullet').removeClass('active').last().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
    }
  }
  dec("after click handled: ");

})}); // click function
```

```css
li.active {
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slider-items">
<li class="slider-item">A</li>
<li class="slider-item">B</li>
<li class="slider-item">C</li>
<li class="slider-item">D</li>
</ul>
<button class="prev">Prev</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```